# Crashing dropwizard application

Tags: java, rest, dropwizard

My dropwizard application keeps shutting down without any error/exception. It has 20 different api calls spread over 3 Dropwizard Resource classes. The api calls require connections to mongo and redis which is initiated in the Application class. The logs look like this,

```
2017-04-20 06:12:00.977 Thread-13 DEBUG o.e.j.u.component.AbstractLifeCycle - stopping org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@76fe48e4
2017-04-20 06:12:00.978 Thread-13 DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - Graceful shutdown org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@76fe48e4 by
2017-04-20 06:12:00.978 Thread-13 DEBUG o.e.j.u.component.AbstractLifeCycle - stopping application@5905282d{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:7004}
2017-04-20 06:12:00.978 Thread-13 DEBUG o.e.j.u.component.AbstractLifeCycle - stopping org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector$ServerConnectorManager@ce5af8b
2017-04-20 06:12:00.979 Thread-13 DEBUG o.e.j.u.component.AbstractLifeCycle - stopping org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector@8ba578f keys=0 selected=0
2017-04-20 06:12:00.979 Thread-13 DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager - Stopping org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector@8ba578f keys=0 selected=0
2017-04-20 06:12:00.979 Thread-13 DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager - Queued change org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector$Stop@1e9ee58d
2017-04-20 06:12:00.979 dw-25-selector-ServerConnectorManager@ce5af8b/0 DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager - Selector loop woken up from select, 0/0 selected
2017-04-20 06:12:00.979 dw-25-selector-ServerConnectorManager@ce5af8b/0 DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager - Running change org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector$Stop@1e9ee58d
2017-04-20 06:12:00.980 Thread-13 DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager - Stopped org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector@8ba578f keys=-1 selected=-1
2017-04-20 06:12:00.980 Thread-13 DEBUG o.e.j.u.component.AbstractLifeCycle - STOPPED org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector@8ba578f keys=-1 selected=-1
2017-04-20 06:12:00.980 dw-25-selector-ServerConnectorManager@ce5af8b/0 DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager - Stopped Thread[dw-25-selector-ServerConnectorManager@ce5af8b/0,5,main] on org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector@8ba578f keys=-1 selected=-1
2017-04-20 06:12:00.980 Thread-13 DEBUG o.e.j.u.component.AbstractLifeCycle - stopping org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector@68481f8e keys=0 selected=0
2017-04-20 06:12:00.980 Thread-13 DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager - Stopping org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector@68481f8e keys=0 selected=0
2017-04-20 06:12:00.980 Thread-13 DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager - Queued change org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector$Stop@51f09baf
```

and this continues to stop all other components until shutting down completely. The problem is similar to this,

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dropwizard-user/QpG1uq-UnnU

Kindly let me know as to why this problem is occurring.

Comment: You haven't described where it happens - your local development environment or on a server somewhere. Any chances that you are hitting [this problem](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dropwizard-user/4L-k1tgPOm0)?

Comment: Looks like the scheduler stops your process, looks into your system message log to find why. Certainly Memory issue or load issue

Comment: @zloster Sorry about that. Yes it is happening on a server. And I am running as the root user. But the problem is still there.

Comment: @Orel yes will check that. Though memory I have checked. I will check on the load